# Does moisture affect electronics?

Tags: pcb, humidity, motherboard

So the situation is the following:

I'm making half a dozen of my own electrical circuits which I would store in a long wooden box along with my micro ATX motherboard and the rest of my pc. The big wooden box is located on top of my room window on the inner side of wall, and was actually storage for outdoor (external) blinds.

I removed the blinds and used PUR foam to seal the gap trough which blinds would roll down. The gap is about 2 meters long and 1 cm wide. On both ends of the gap I left about 3-5 cm whole for cooling of my electronics. Now the winter came, I am afraid of moisture and condensation?

Will my electronics and PC get moisture and die off eventually?

Comment: Water conducts so it can effect circuit behaviour (sometimes catastrophically).  However, a lot depends on environmental conditions. It's certainly possible to design electronics to survive outdoor conditions.  If enclosures are suitably designed and steps taken to ensure moisture does not build up.

Answer (score 3):

Two situations I encountered: -

Situation 1 - sensitive electronic measurement circuit cooled down to below 0degC - no problem but, on warming and reaching a temperature just above zero, spurious signals and noise occurs - water droplets formed on the surface of the PCB - solution - dry the PCB and apply a good layer of water resistant varnish/lacquer - it never happened again.

Situation 2 - a power supply module located low inside a "fully sealed" enclosure - it worked for about 2 years then went pop. Reason, each night the box got turned off and as it cooled down it "dragged" warm moist air into the enclosure. The moisture settled on the base of the inside of the enclosure. This happened 6 days a week for about two years and there was about 1cm of water slopping around when it was inspected.

These are real events and both needed different solutions. Situation 1 was a totally open enclosure that was going through a design stage to see how it performed against temeprature cycling with humidity. The second situation was entirely different but equally problematic for regions that suffer high humidity.

My best advise is leave a hole for any water to drain out and have PCBs mounted vertically for least chances of problems.

My other advice is don't put reasonably high powered electronics in a wooden box - it's a fire hazard.

Answer (score 1):

> Will my electronics and PC get moisture and die off eventually?

I would say that if these circuit boards are generating plenty of heat, so that you have to leave gaps for cooling, and if these circuits are on 24 hours a day, then the heat should prevent condensation from forming.

The reason is that the warmed air has a lower relative humidity.

Condensation will generally form in cold areas of the room, on cold objects, like window panes, not inside a heated box.

I would go ahead with the install, and inspect it a few times during its first cold, wet season for peace of mind; but I suspect you will find everything dry.

Do seal the space against the entry of exterior air and moisture.